# reading a list from a file with a counter in python

Tags: python, arrays

So I've got it to work, but I can't get my text from my textfile to read individually line by line.

It just comes out the whole `.txt` file, the prompt is wanted btw.

```
print "Type the filename again:"
file_again = raw_input("> ")
txt_again = open(file_again)
```

Comment: Hmm...`with open(file) as f: f.readlines()` or `with open(file) as f: f.read().splitlines()` or `with open(file) as f: for i in f: ...`? What do you mean about *with a counter* ?

Comment: I wanted a counter to go through with my txt file. so i'd read in line by line and it would print out what the count is.

Comment: So count what? What's your expect output?

Answer (score 0):

You want to walk through the file like this:

```
print("Type the filename again:")
file_again = raw_input("> ")

lines = []
with open(file_again, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        # do whatever you need to
```

The `with` statement makes sure to close the file for you once its finished and the `for` walks through the file line by line

Comment: I want  to use an array of counters to keep track of the number of each number of items in the file so thats why I wanted the counter, it's the syntax that gets me I'm coming from VB to python so slowly getting it.

Comment: I've never used or heard of with, what kind of statement is it?

Comment: `with` statement [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) is a context statement, you open a file in it and then use it in the `with` block. When you exit the block, Python will take care of cleaning up the context. So in this case it will close the file for you.

Comment: I've been trying the code above, but I'm getting synntax errors after the> for line in f: (thats when I'm trying to read line by line)

Answer (score 0):

If you need a counter as you wrote in the heading of your question, you could use enumerate:

```
print("Type the filename again:")
file_again = raw_input("> ")

with open(file_again,'r') as f:
    for linenumber, line in enumerate(f):
        # process all lines one by one
```